# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, thymeleaf

I am writing a unit test for `AuthService.confirmEmail` method. However, I get `Template cannot be null` exception. I already have this template under this path `resources/templates/emailConfirmed.html`. Even if I didn't have this template, spring shouldn't be throwing this error because `SpringTemplateEngine` is mocked. I don't know why I see this error. Any suggestion?

This is the actual method.

**AuthService**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthService {

    private final EmailConfirmationService emailConfirmationService;
    private final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    //....

     @Transactional
    public String confirmEmail(String token) {
        EmailConfirmationToken confirmationToken;
        try {
            confirmationToken = emailConfirmationService
                    .getToken(token);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
            return buildEmailConfirmedPage("Geçersiz token!");
        }
        if (confirmationToken.getConfirmedAt() != null) {
            return buildEmailConfirmedPage("E-posta zaten onaylandı.");
        }

        if (emailConfirmationService.isTokenExpired(confirmationToken)) {
            return buildEmailConfirmedPage("E-posta onayı zaman aşımına uğradı!");
        }
        emailConfirmationService.setConfirmedAt(token);
        appUserService.enableAppUser(confirmationToken.getAppUser().getEmail());
        return buildEmailConfirmedPage("E-posta adresi onaylandı. Bu sayfayı kapatabilirsin.");
    }

    private String buildEmailConfirmedPage(String message) {
        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("message", message);
        return templateEngine.process("emailConfirmed", context);
    }

}
```

**AuthServiceTest**

```
import com.napsam.wo.entities.EmailConfirmationToken;
import com.napsam.wo.entities.AppUser;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.thymeleaf.context.Context;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;


import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AuthServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private EmailConfirmationService emailConfirmationService;

    @Mock
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

   //.. other mocks

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthService underTest;


    @Test
    void confirmEmail_success() {
        //given
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        EmailConfirmationToken emailConfirmationToken = new EmailConfirmationToken();
        emailConfirmationToken.setExpiresAt(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10));
        AppUser appUser = new AppUser();
        appUser.setEmail("test");
        emailConfirmationToken.setAppUser(appUser);
        //when
        when(emailConfirmationService.getToken(token)).thenReturn(emailConfirmationToken);
        when(emailConfirmationService.isTokenExpired(emailConfirmationToken)).thenReturn(false);

        when(templateEngine.process(eq("index"), any(Context.class))).thenReturn("asdaasdas");

        String result = underTest.confirmEmail(token);

        //then
        verify(appUserService, times(1)).enableAppUser(emailConfirmationToken.getAppUser().getEmail());
        assertThat(result, containsString("E-posta adresi onaylandı."));
    }

   //other cases ...

}
```

**Error full stack trace**

```
//AuthServiceTest.java:294 is the line where `templateEngine.process` is called.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template cannot be null

    at org.thymeleaf.util.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:37)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateSpec.<init>(TemplateSpec.java:314)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1048)
    at com.napsam.wo.service.AuthServiceTest.confirmEmail_success(AuthServiceTest.java:294)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Comment: You need `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` on your `AuthServiceTest` class, otherwise the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations won't be used.

Comment: I already have this annotation. I just forgot to add it when I remove the parts that are irrelevant from the question. I will update the question

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @tgdavies, the question is updated with the stack trace.

Comment: Is that your actual code now? You're not mixing Spring annotations on your test?

Comment: @tgdavies yes all of them are correct. I checked each one, they are imported from the right package.

Comment: And there are no other annotations on your test class?

Comment: When I run the test in debug mode, I realized that spring tries to execute `template.process` method, when the debug line is on `when(templateEngine.process...)`. It shouldn't be running this line before `underTest.confirmEmail()`. It should run `template.process` method inside the actual method(`AuthService.confirmEmail`)

Comment: `templateEngine` should be a mock at that point. Are there any other annotations, inheritance or `@Before/@BeforeAll` methods on your test that you haven't shown?

Comment: I dont have any setUp method. (@Before, @BeforeAll, @BeforeEach etc.)  I also tried to mock the template engine inside the method but it also didn't work.  ```SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine1 = mock(SpringTemplateEngine.class);     when(templateEngine1.process(eq("index"),any(Context.class))).thenReturn("asdaasdas");```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete, minimal example which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @tgdavies I updated the question with the full and relevant code.